# loop for two files only prints first line python

Tags: python, file, loops, line

- The first file, `f1` has two columns, the first being an `ID number` and the second being a `value associated` with it.
- The second file, `f2` is a bigger version of the first file with more values and `six columns` but includes the two from the first file.
- The second file has a column I want to associate with the values in the first file and I want the output to be a new `text file` that contains the `ID`,
- the value associated and another column with the ones I want to associate from the bigger second file.
- So far I've made a code which is doing what I want however it's only printing out the first line.
- I'm not fantastic at python which is probably noticeable in my code, and I was hoping someone will have the answer to my problem

  ```
  import csv    
  with open('output1.txt','w') as out1,open('list1.csv') as f1,open('list2.csv') as f2:  
  csvf1=csv.reader(f1)
  csvf2=csv.reader(f2)
  for txt1 in csvf1:
      id1=txt1[0]
      z1=txt1[1]

      for txt2 in csvf2:
          id2=txt2[0]
          z2=txt2[3]
          ra=txt2[1]
          if id1==id2:
             out1.write("{} {} {}\n".format(id2,z1,ra))

  out1.close()
  f1.close()
  f2.close()
  ```
- I would also like to point out that using `.split(',')` does not work on my files for some reason just in case someone tries to use it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find my answer from another programmer and this was the code that ended up working.

Thank you so much for your answers for they were close to what worked.

```
import csv 
with open('output1.txt','w') as out1, open('file1.csv') as f1:
     csvf1=csv.reader(f1)

     for txt1 in csvf1:
           id1=txt1[0]
           z1=txt1[1]

           with open('file2.csv') as f2: 
               csvf2=csv.reader(f2)
               for txt2 in csvf2:
                   id2=txt2[0]
                   z2=txt2[3]
                   ra=txt2[1]
                   if id1 == id2:
                       out1.write("{} {} {}\n".format(id2,z1,ra))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the line csvf2=csv.reader(f2) inside the first loop. The inner loop will get executed only for the first line. For the second line, inner loop will not get executed as the filereader marker is already at the end of the file.

```
import csv    
with open('output1.txt','w') as out1,open('list1.csv') as f1,open('list2.csv') as f2:  
    csvf1=csv.reader(f1)

    for txt1 in csvf1:
        id1=txt1[0]
        z1=txt1[1]
        csvf2=csv.reader(f2)
        for txt2 in csvf2:
            id2=txt2[0]
            z2=txt2[3]
            ra=txt2[1]
            if id1==id2:
               out1.write("{} {} {}\n".format(id2,z1,ra))

out1.close()
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cvs.reader()` is a function which you can only iterate the result of it **once**, (is it a `yield` function? some one should correct me, I just dig into the source code and got stuck at *buildin-module* of object `reader()`. any way, it just behave like a yield function)

So you may need to save every row in a temp array for farther usage:

```
 list1 = []
 with open('list1.txt') as fp:
     for row in csv.reader(fp):
          list1.append(row)
```

By the way, you wont need to close a `fp` explicitly when open it with a `with` expression, the mechanism just do that for you when you get out of the `with` scope.